# Can't Edit a WPF Template Column Value

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid

I have a class called Donation which contains a AmountPaid decimal property.  I have an ObservableCollection(of Donation) which is the ItemsSource of my wpf datagrid.  Here is the complete definition of the AmountPaid column.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn
    DisplayIndex="3">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox
                Style="{StaticResource styHeader}"
                Text="Amount Paid">
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
               Style="{StaticResource styMoney}"
                Text="{Binding Path=AmountPaid, StringFormat=c0}">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Path=AmountPaid, StringFormat=c0}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When I click in this column, it won't allow any edits and I do not understand why.  Here are some questions that have come up as I have tried to fix the problem:

1. Should I bind both the CellTemplate and the CellEditingTemplate or just one of them?  If the latter, which one?
2. Do I even need the CellEditingTemplate?  I've seen examples where, for instance, a DatePicker is put in the CellTemplate.  Why does this work if, as I understand it, the CellTemplate is only for displaying the data.
3. I have tried setting the Binding Mode = TwoWay but that doesn't change the fact that the column value can't be changed by the user.

Comment: Just replace the TextBlock in the CellEditingTemplate with a TextBox and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you put a `TextBlock` in the editing template. `TextBlock`s are not editable. You probably meant to put a `TextBox`.

However, I would suggest that you simply use `DataGridTextBoxColumn` instead.

You do not have to provide a `CellEditingTemplate`, you can put an editable control directly in the `CellTemplate` and omit the `CellEditingTemplate`. However, if you do this you are loosing some of the built in functionality of the `DataGrid` pertaining to edit mode, edit mode events, and preventing or canceling edits. It may also potentially cause strange UI quirks or confuse users who may be familiar with the way data grids are typically supposed to work.

It can also have a potential performance impact since editable controls like `TextBox` or `ComboBox` are typically “heavier” then simple read only controls like `TextBlock`. The controls in the editing template will only get created and rendered  as they are needed when the cell is put in edit mode (and only one cell is in edit mode at a time). Controls in the cell template are all always present and being rendered (if you have virtualization enabled, it’s only controls for cells that are currently visible, but that’s still potentially a lot more than one at a time).

Comment: I was using a Template column only because I thought I needed that in order to have a custom header.  But I fixed that and changed those columns to Text columns.  But the key was noting the use of a TextBlock instead of a TextBox.  Fixed.